# Option toggled in Settings.app not always detected in applicationDidBecomeActive

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, settings, root.plist

I have a Root.plist file which is used for my app's settings. It has a toggle switch with an identifier of `reset_achievements_preference`. In the `applicationDidBecomeActive` method, I have this code:

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    NSLog(@"reset achievements: %i", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"reset_achievements_preference"]);

    if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"reset_achievements_preference"]) {
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:NO forKey:@"reset_achievements_preference"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

        //Code to react to this change
    }
}
```

Sometimes it hits the NSLog and notices the object change, but sometimes it doesn't. I wonder if I'm dealing with this incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize]
```

To `applicationDidBecomeActive:` before anything else to refresh the status of the user defaults. Thy [`synchronize`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSUserDefaults/synchronize) method is called periodically by the application, but you can refresh it manually.

Answer (score 0):

When do you want to handle your `reset_achievements_preference` option? The method `applicationDidBecomeActive` is called when the application starts and when the application returns from background (is brought to foreground by the user).

If you want to handle `reset_achievements_preference` only at application startup, it is possible that the user puts your app into background, then returns to it. In this case `applicationDidBecomeActive` is called and it sets `reset_achievements_preference` to NO which probably is not what you want.

You can simply move this code to [application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application%3adidFinishLaunchingWithOptions%3a) method to solve this problem.

Comment: I want it to happen each time the user comes back to my app. Right now, I can change the toggle to be YES, and then come back to my app and it'll say the value is NO.